# How Can I Source My $Profile From A Powershell Function?

Tags: scripting, powershell

I like to make a lot of changes to my $profile file. After saving a change, I would like to source the file using an "sop" alias. Here's how I hope to accomplish that:

```
set-alias sop Source-Profile
function Source-Profile {
    . $profile
}
```

This function does not throw any errors, so it appears to work. However, when I do make changes to my $profile file, this function doesn’t appear to to anything. I still have to type `. $profile` from the PS prompt to re-evaluate that file. And that's ok, but it is a minor pain. I would rather use an alias to source that file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot-sourcing a file runs it in the current scope (rather than its own scope).  To source a file in a function and get the definitions in the file to be included in the calling scope, you need to dot-source the function.
Try this:

```
. sop
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Too bad though that you can't do this without the dot. This sort of thing works in BASH and such.